# Logic to set a bits of given number from first occurance of bits 1 as given example?

Tags: c, bit

Logic to set a bits of given number (as show in example  below) from first  occurance of 1  next should must be 1 and then alternative 0 and 1 should continue till all bits field is filled up? example if num =10 then its binary is 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010
out put should be 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1101

similar if it is 16 10000 then 0/p should be 11010 and if 15 ie 1111 then output 11010 when we get first bits as 1 in give number  then next bits should be 1 and the alternative 0 and 1?my logic is below please help to fix it

```
int main()
    {   
     int i,onetime=1,flag=1;
     scanf("%d",&num);

     for(i=31;i>=0;i++)
     {
      if(num & 1<<i)
      break;     // this will give first set bits of num ie 1
     }

     --i;  // move to next adjacent bit and this should also be 1


     for(;i>0;)
     {
       if(onetime=1)   // here forcely making 1
       {
         num=num|1<<i;
         onetime=0;
       }

       if(flag==1)  // set to 0 
       {
         num=num&~(1<<i) 
         flag=0;
       }

       if(flag==0)  //set to 1
       {
         num=num|(1<<i);  
         flag =1-flag;  //will keep on switch 0 and 1
       }

     }

   }
```

Comment: Word what you are trying to say better. This is really confusing.

Comment: You say that 15 should become 11010. Shouldn't it be 1101?

Comment: Why not find the **most significant bit**, then alternate from that position to `0`.

Comment: @Iserni no its 11010 only when 1st one is found then second is also 1 then anternative 0 then 1 and soon till all bits get filled up

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  i did same as way above.i am finding first 1 from MSB and then next most made 1 after that 0 then 1 0 1 ... and so  on

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand. Following your logic, 15 decimal ought to become 1101. Yet you state it should become 11010. Why does the *fifth* bit get set, when 15 decimal is only 1111 binary?

Comment: @Iserni see 15 is 1111 now when i found first 1 from msb then next adjuscent bits must be 1 ie->11 now remaning 2 bit will be alternate as 0 then 1 and so on... hence we will get o/p as 1101

Comment: Your logic should work - I have a slightly different algorithm if you're interested - but you have not defined `i, `num`, `onetime` or `flag`. These last two especially, do they start from 0 or from 1?

Comment: @Think take a look at the answer. That's why I say, the logic is fairly trivial, the implementation is a bit challenging.

Comment: @Iserni onetime and flag are set to 1 for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the logic behind doing what you want to do it fairly trivial, the implementation isn't. Ignoring the need to output a binary representation for the moment, the logic can be broken down to:

```
1.)  finding the most significant bit (msb)
2.)  toggling each bit beginning at (msb - 1) to 0 (subtracting 'x' from msb)
3.)    setting each bit if (x % 2) == 0, clearing otherwise
```

The implementation isn't difficult, it is just rather involved (**note: this is for 32-bit values only**):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>  /* for CHAR_BIT            */

inline int getmsb (uint32_t x);
char *fmtbinstr_32 (uint32_t x, const size_t szgrp, char *sep);

/* set or clear bit n */
inline void bit_set     (uint32_t *bf, int n) { *bf |= (1 << n); }
inline void bit_clear   (uint32_t *bf, int n) { *bf &= ~(1 << n); }

int
main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: insufficient input, usage: %s int\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    uint32_t number = (uint32_t)atoi (argv[1]);
    uint32_t newnum = number;
    int msb = getmsb (number);
    int it = 0;

    printf ("\n number: %s\n msb   : %d\n\n", fmtbinstr_32 (number, 4, "-"), msb);

    it = (int)msb;

    for (it = 1; it <= msb; it++) {
        if ((it % 2) == 0)
            bit_clear (&newnum, msb - it);
        else
            bit_set (&newnum, msb - it);
    }

    printf (" newnum: %s\n\n", fmtbinstr_32 (newnum, 4, "-"));

    return 0;
}

/* return the most significant bit MSB for the value supplied (bit scan reverse)
* for 32-bit values. For 64-bit values, use 'bsrq'.
*/
inline int getmsb (uint32_t x)
{
    asm ("bsr %0, %0" : "=r" (x) : "0" (x));
    return x;
}

/* binary string of uint32_t x, in szgrp bits groups, separated by sep */
char *fmtbinstr_32 (uint32_t x, const size_t szgrp, char *sep)
{
    char b [sizeof(uint32_t) * CHAR_BIT + 1] = {0};
    static char fmtb [sizeof (uint32_t) * 2 * CHAR_BIT] = {0};
    const size_t len = sizeof(uint32_t) * CHAR_BIT + 1;
    register size_t z = 0;
    register size_t idx = 0;

    if (szgrp > ((len - 1) / 2) || szgrp <= 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: invalid input: szgrp '%d' out of range (%d >= szgrp > 0)\n", __func__, (int) szgrp, (int) ((len - 1) / 2));
        return NULL; // could make b static and return b instead
    }

    for (z = 0; z < len - 1; z++)
        b [sizeof (uint32_t) * CHAR_BIT - 1 - z] = ((x>>z) & 0x1) ? '1' : '0';

    if (sep [0] == '\0') {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: invalid input: 'sep' is undefined or empty string\n", __func__);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (z = 0; z < len - 1; z++) {
        if ((len - 1 - z) % szgrp == 0 && z > 0) {
            fmtb [idx] = sep [0];
            idx++;
        }
        fmtb [idx] = b [z];
        idx++;
    }

    fmtb [idx] = '\0';
    return fmtb;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/bitalt 10

 number: 0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-1010
 msb   : 3

 newnum: 0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-1101

$ ./bin/bitalt 55

 number: 0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0011-0111
 msb   : 5

 newnum: 0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0011-0101
```

---

**Basic Version**

This version employs the same logic, but leaves out the binary print function and the getmsb function that uses assembler instructions to get the most significant bit. This example uses most of the logic from the original question, but adjust the loops as needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int i = 0, msb = 0;
    unsigned int num = 0;

    printf ("\nEnter a number: ");
    scanf ("%u", &num);

    for (i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (num & 1 << i)
            break;         // this will give first set bits of num ie 1
    }                      // which is the most significant bit (msb)

    msb = i;               // save msb

    printf ("\n The most significant bit (msb): %d\n", msb);

    // we want the index [msb - i] to step down from (msb-1) to 0
    // e.g. if num=10, then msb=3, so we want the indexes to be 2,1,0
    // so let i start at 1 and we will do (msb -i) until i=msb
    for (i = 1; i <= msb; i++) {
        if ((i % 2) == 0)               // if i mod 2 == 0, we clear the bit
            num &= ~(1 << (msb - i));   // clear_bit (make it 0)
        else
            num |= (1 << (msb - i));    // set_bit (make it 1)
    }

    printf ("\n The resulting number is: %u\n\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/bas

Enter a number: 10

 The most significant bit (msb): 3

 The resulting number is: 13

$ ./bin/bas

Enter a number: 55

 The most significant bit (msb): 5

 The resulting number is: 53
```

Comment: C.Rankin thanks Your logic is correct but i am unable to figure out it

Comment: C.Rankin can u please point out where i went wrong in my code because your code is too tough for me to analysis ?

Comment: OK - hold on. I'll take a look. If you ignore my `fmtbinstr_32` function that just prints the binary string, the rest should be fairly easy. Also, you don't have to use my `msb` or `bit_set` or `bit_clear`, you can do that any way you like. I've just collected some of the most efficient ways of doing it, that include either bit shifts or inline assembly language.

Comment: @Think - take a look at the bottom answer. Make sure you understand what is being done. If you have questions, just let me know. It has the same logic as the first. Save both versions. When you have time, take the time to learn what the first version does. There are a lot of very useful concepts presented.